# Is it correct to say that the natural numbers are a proper subset of the integers?

Tags: integers, natural-numbers

Is it correct to say that the natural numbers are a proper subset of the integers? $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

Just want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: God, no way. The integers contain all sorts of GMO numbers and the like. Stick with organic numbers.

Comment: @copper.hat I have flagged your comment for moderator attention. There is no scientific evidence that GMO numbers are inferior to organic numbers.

Comment: Yes, but still $\Bbb Z$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb N$. So there is a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: ...but the bijection is not induced by the subset inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

The natural numbers are subset of integers.

However, the natural numbers do not include any negative integer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick confirmation.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, if you want to be really precise about it, strictly speaking ℕ is NOT a subset of ℤ.

The reason for this is that, when constructing the integers, we define them as equivalence classes and therefore the positive integers are not the same kind of mathematical objects as the natural numbers.

But, since it can be shown that N is order isomorphic to the positive Integers, then for all practical purposes you can treat ℕ as if it was in fact a subset of ℤ.

Comment: Undoubtedly N is subset of Z,  since atleast we.are in a position  to find atleast one element which is there Z but not in N and. Even all the elements of N lies in Z

Comment: @nimmy, there certainly is a bijection between the elements of N and the positive Integers and they do behave precisely the same way, but, as I said, they are not the same kind of mathematical objects, but you could say the following not-so-formal statement: For any natural number n, there exists some positive integer z such that n and z behave the same way with regards to their ordering and some operation. But, to be clear, this distinction is really irrelevant for all practical purposes. It only comes up when trying to formally construct the integers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Integers are the essentially the natural numbers and their opposites, plus zero.

Since $\Bbb Z$ contains one or more element not found in $\Bbb N$ (namely $0$ and the negative numbers) and all elements of $\Bbb N$ are found in $\Bbb Z$, then $\Bbb N$ is a proper subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: the two sets are not equal, and for any $n \in \mathbf{N}$, we have $n \in \mathbf{Z}$.