# Are there any formal set theories in which N, Z, Q, and R are subsets of each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I've recently learned that unlike in naive set theory, $N\not\subset Z\not\subset Q\not\subset R$ in ZFC.

Here are some discussions on it:

- [Why are integers subset of reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055501/why-are-integers-subset-of-reals/)
- [Is it correct to say that the natural numbers are a proper subset of the integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712776/is-it-correct-to-say-that-the-natural-numbers-are-a-proper-subset-of-the-integer/)

I was wondering if there were any **widely-accepted** and **formal** set theories in which $N\subset Z\subset Q\subset R$, just as our intuition tells us.

Comment: You can define the reals axiomatically, then extract from that the naturals, or the rationals, or the integers, or whatever.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2437917/

Comment: Well, $\Bbb N\subseteq\Bbb Z$ *is* literally true if you just take a particular model of $\Bbb Z$ that contains another particular model of $\Bbb N$. Because remember we only care about these objects in terms of their abstract behaviour than what their literal elements are. And all of that works in ZFC. $\Bbb N\not\subset\Bbb Z$ is not a symptom of ZFC, it's a symptom of the canonical ways in which $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ are constructed. But equally one could construct $\Bbb Z$ in the canonical way and define $\Bbb N$ to be its positive subset. Whatever

Comment: This is not a question of the set theory, but rather of the definitions we make in the set theory. ZFC on its own says nothing about these number systems - we have to define them. According to the  standard constructions / definitions, these number systems are not contained in each other, but it's easy to modify the definitions (without modifying ZFC in any way!) so that they are contained in each other.

Comment: @XanderHenderson what if we also have complex numbers? and quaternions? and octonions? and...? There is really no mother set that contains all of these, so I think defining the smaller ones based on the bigger ones is not going to work out. We have to do the opposite and define bigger ones based on the smaller ones.

Comment: @FShrike what about $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$? what about $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman could you please give a link to those "standard constructions / definitions"? is there a reasonable consensus on them in the math community?

Comment: @SMMH Yes, there is a reasonable consensus. Open up any introductory set theory textbook. *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrabacek and Jech is a good choice. Or Googling "set theoretic construction of number systems" gives a number of references.

Comment: Regarding your comment to @XanderHenderson: Let's say you have a construction of $\mathbb{N}$ and a construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ according to which $\mathbb{N}\not\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, and you're dissatisfied with this situation. Well, we have an injective function $i\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ mapping each natural number to "its copy" in the integers. Now you're free to define $Z' = (\mathbb{Z}\setminus i(\mathbb{N})) \cup \mathbb{N}$ (that is, remove the "copies" and replace them with the "real" natural numbers) and call $Z'$ the "integers" instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Which is, indeed, *exactly* what I suggested doing in the answer I linked:  "Alternatively, instead of declaring the existence of the reals by fiat (item 5, above), we could build them up from scratch via the usual process (i.e. build the integers as equivalence classes of naturals, then the rationals as equivalence classes of integers, then the reals as Dedekind cuts). This construction of the reals will satisfy the above axioms. Then, you can build the real natural numbers via the ["inductive set" definition in the question]." ;)

Comment: It makes no difference if you do this, since there is a canonical bijection $\mathbb{Z}\to Z'$, so anything "structural" (i.e., not looking under the hood at what set happens to represent what number) that you can prove about $\mathbb{Z}$, you can also prove about $Z'$. Now there was nothing special about $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ here. If you do this systematically as you define each larger number system, you can obtain $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}\subset\dots$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Oh yes, I see. I didn't click though, sorry!

Comment: @AlexKruckman No, I probably rambled on too long, and didn't make that point obvious enough. :D